# Parsing a data feed results in a Invalid Character error in WinJS

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winjs

I am calling the Flickr data feed in WinJS for a Windows 8 Metro App. When I attempt to parse the feed response with JSON.parse, I get an Invalid Character error. Here is my code:

```
function processPhotos(result)
{
    var photoData = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
    //bind here
    data.items.forEach(function (item) {
        list.push(item);
    });
}

function processError(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}

WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json" }).then(processPhotos, processError);
WinJS.Namespace.define("data", {
    items: groupedItems,
    groups: groupedItems.groups,
    getItemsFromGroup: getItemsFromGroup
});
```

Result.ResponseText has the expected content.

Does anyone else encounter this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the data, you will notice it's not JSON, it's [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). That's the reason why `JSON.parse()` can't process it. If you want normal JSON, according to [the documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html), you should use `nojsoncallback=1`:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1
```

Comment: You are right! I don't know as much about JSON as I thought. Interestingly, even with the nojsoncallback parameter I get an Invalid Character. I got some advice on Twitter to run it through a JSON validator, and lo and behold, there are actually invalid characters in the response! So, problem one solved, but problem two crops up. Thanks for the info, though. I learned something.

Comment: That's weird, it did work for me when I tried it both with JSON.NET and then with your code in WinJS.

Comment: It is time based. If there is a comment with a weird character in it, then it fails. I just got it to fail, then work, then fail. Interesting. Gotta find a better demo URL I guess.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do this to clear out some of the invalid characters in the responseText. (suggested to me by https://stackoverflow.com/users/200698/devhammer)

```
var cleansed = result.responseText.replace(/\\'/g, "'");
var photoData = JSON.parse(cleansed).d;
```

Comment: Yes! You are my hero. I've been looking for a solution to the terrible JSON I received from Flickr, and this is it! I can't understand why they provide us with such messed up JSON.

Comment: Just in case someone else hits this for other languages - in ObjC the cleaning code is: NSString *cleanString = [respString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\'" withString:@"'"];